# About $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx=\lim_{t\to b-0\\s\to a+0} \int_{s}^{t} f(x)dx$ ("Introduction to Analysis" by Kunihiko Kodaira)

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I am reading "Introduction to Analysis" (in Japanese) by Kunihiko Kodaira.

> If $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to b-0\\s\to a+0} \int_{s}^{t} f(x)dx$ exists for a function $f(x)$ which is continuous on an interval $(a,b)$, then we define $$\tag{4.35}\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx=\lim_{t\to b-0\\s\to a+0} \int_{s}^{t} f(x)dx.$$
> (4.35) means for any positive real number $\epsilon$, there exists a positive real number $\delta(\epsilon)$ such that if $b-\delta(\epsilon)<t<b$ and $a<s<a+\delta(\epsilon)$, then $$\left|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx-\int_{s}^{t}f(x)dx\right|<\epsilon.$$
> If we choose a point $c$ such that $a<c<b$, then $$\int_{s}^{t}f(x)dx=\int_{s}^{c}f(x)dx+\int_{c}^{t}f(x)dx.$$
> So, $$\lim_{t\to b-0\\s\to a+0}\int_{s}^{t}f(x)dx=\lim_{s\to a+0}\int_{s}^{c}f(x)dx+\lim_{t\to b-0}\int_{c}^{t}f(x)dx.$$
> Therefore we can also write (4.35) as follows: $$\tag{4.36}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\lim_{s\to a+0}\int_{s}^{c}f(x)dx+\lim_{t\to b-0}\int_{c}^{t}f(x)dx.$$

My question is here:

> I can prove that if $\displaystyle\lim_{s\to a+0} \int_{s}^{c} f(x)dx$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to b-0} \int_{c}^{t} f(x)dx$ exist for a function $f(x)$ which is continuous on an interval $(a,b)$ and for a point $c$ such that $a<c<b$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to b-0\\s\to a+0} \int_{s}^{t} f(x)dx$ exists.

> How to prove the following?
> If $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to b-0\\s\to a+0} \int_{s}^{t} f(x)dx$ exists for a function $f(x)$ which is continuous on an interval $(a,b)$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{s\to a+0} \int_{s}^{c} f(x)dx$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to b-0} \int_{c}^{t} f(x)dx$ exist for a point $c$ such that $a<c<b$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C:=\displaystyle\lim_{t\to b-0\\s\to a+0} \int_{s}^{t} f(x)dx$.
Let $c$ be an arbitrary real number such that $a<c<b$.
Let $F(x):=\int_{c}^{x} f(t) dt$.
Let $\epsilon$ be an arbitrary positive real number.
By assumption, there exists a positive real number $\delta(\frac{\epsilon}{2})$ such that for any $s\in(a,a+\delta(\frac{\epsilon}{2}))$ and for any $x\in (b-\delta(\frac{\epsilon}{2}),b)$,$$\left|C-\int_{s}^{x}f(x)dx\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$ holds.
Let $x,y\in (b-\delta(\frac{\epsilon}{2}),b)$.
Then, $$\left|F(x)-F(y)\right|=\left|\int_{s}^{x}f(t)dt-\int_{s}^{y}f(t)dt\right|\leq\left|\int_{s}^{x}f(t)dt-C\right|+\left|C-\int_{s}^{y}f(t)dt\right|<\epsilon.$$
So, by Cauchy's criterion, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to b-0} F(x)$ exists.
Let $G(x):=\int_{x}^{c} f(t) dt$.
Similary, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a+0} G(x)$ exists

Comment: Nicely done (+1).  To be clear you are using $\left|F(x)-F(y)\right|=\left|\int_{c}^{x}f(t)dt-\int_{c}^{y}f(t)dt\right| = \left|\int_{c}^{x}f(t)dt+ \int_{s}^{c}f(t)dt-\int_{c}^{y}f(t)dt- \int_{s}^{c}f(t)dt\right|$  where $c$ is any point in $(a,b)$ and $s <c$ is chosen to be in $(a,a+\delta)$.

Comment: @RRL Thank you very much for your comment.